# run batch code directly from variable instead of script file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have code similar to the following running on a few of my windows machines:

**mybatch.bat**

```
::set destdir=C:\SServer\var\db\hist\log-entry
set fileage=-7
set destdir="C:\SServer\var\db\hist\audit-log - Copy"
set recordsdir=C:\housekeeping\LOGS
set info_tempfile=%recordsdir%\cleanup.info
set status_tempfile=%recordsdir%\cleanup.status
set count_tempfile=%recordsdir%\cleanup.count
::set filepattern=log_exception-
set filepattern=AuditLog-
::set filepattern=temip
 
if not exist %recordsdir% (mkdir %recordsdir%)
 
if not exist %recordsdir% (
        echo %DATE% %TIME% ERROR: Unable to create records directory [ %recordsdir% ] 1>> %status_tempfile%
)
 
forfiles -p %destdir% -s -m *%filepattern%* /D %fileage% /C "cmd /c echo /q @path" 2> %info_tempfile% 1> %count_tempfile%
```

I'm new to batch script so please forgive any abomination you may spot in the above code.  What i'm trying to do here is identify how I can go about running code stored in a variable.

For instance, in powershell, you can run any piece of powershell code if you store it in a script block and pass it to the `iex` or `invoke-expression` command.

```
$scriptBlock = {
$welcomeMsg = "Hello, World!"
$welcomeMsg
}
iex "$scriptBlock"
```

I'm wondering if the same exist for batch?

How do I store the above batch code (mybatch.bat) in a variable and then pass it to say `cmd.exe` and have it execute as though it were in a file?

Comment: What's wrong with storing it in the file it's already in and `calling` it from `cmd.exe`  with `call "mybatch-.bat"`. Other than that, depending upon what you were intending to do, you could turn your commands into a one liner, and run it with `cmd /c %onelinervariable%`. This site is not however appropriate to ask use to convert all of those individual commands into a one liner for you though, so please don't ask.

Comment: `set name="pathtofile" && %name%`?

Comment: Define a given code block in the Macro style using setx to add it to the system environmental variables